# Floating point precison format

Tags: c++, precision

I have a float variable and it is value 2.3456533424. I want to use that variable like 2.34 or 2.345. How I change float number precision?

I want to  this change use a different numeric operation. I dont want to use like string.

Comment: Use how? To print to screen? To use in an expression?

Comment: I do not convert this value string format. I use the float value with new value to numeric operations.

Comment: Use `std::round(x * 100) / 100`.

Answer (score -3):

you can use setPrecision(int) where the int is the number of places you want to use.